# How to ensure Java threads run in a particular order

Tags: java

Given three threads, 1-3, that print a letter, A-C, how can I guarantee the output order?

I would like the output of the threads to be "ABCABCABC"

Comment: Are you forced to use threads or could you just do the stuff in one thread instead?

Comment: This is a school assignment right? Look up how to do synchronization in Java.

Answer (score 4):

Threads run independently, so you will never get such output unless you perform special efforts to synchronize your threads. 3 threads that are running independently are expected to print "random" output because it is up to OS to schedule the threads.

Answer (score 4):

This may not be what threads supposed to do but, it can be achieved by simply using join (which asks the start*ING* thread to wait for the completion of the start*ED* thread.

```
class A implements Runnable {

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(12);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("ClassA : A");
}

}

class B implements Runnable {

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(12);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("ClassB : B");
}

}

class C implements Runnable {

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(12);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("ClassC : C");
}

}

public class OrderedThreadApp {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Thread a = new Thread(new A());
    Thread b = new Thread(new B());
    Thread c = new Thread(new C());

    a.start();
    try {
        a.join();
        b.start();
        b.join();
        c.start();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by combining `CountDownLatch` and `CyclicBarrier`. Here is the sample code:

```
    package org.orange.didxga;

import java.util.concurrent.BrokenBarrierException;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier;

public class ThreadExecutionOrder {

    private CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(2);
    private CountDownLatch countDownLatch1 = new CountDownLatch(1);
    private CyclicBarrier barrier;
    private final Object monitor = new Object();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new ThreadExecutionOrder().test();
    }

    public void test() {
        Runnable t1 = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.print("A");
                countDownLatch1.countDown();
                countDownLatch.countDown();
                try {
                    barrier.await();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (BrokenBarrierException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        };
        Runnable t2 = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    countDownLatch1.await();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.print("B");
                countDownLatch.countDown();
                try {
                    barrier.await();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (BrokenBarrierException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        };
        Runnable t3 = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    countDownLatch.await();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.print("C");
                try {
                    barrier.await();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (BrokenBarrierException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        };
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            barrier = new CyclicBarrier(3, new Runnable()  {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    synchronized (monitor) {
                        countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(2);
                        countDownLatch1 = new CountDownLatch(1);
                        monitor.notify();
                    }
                }

            });
            new Thread(t1).start();
            new Thread(t2).start();
            new Thread(t3).start();
            synchronized (monitor) {
                try {
                    monitor.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Nice. This solves it. Do you need the `CyclicBarrier` though? Wouldn't `Thread.join` be sufficient? Also do you need O(n) latches (and therefore O(n^2) countdowns)? Each thread could just `countdown` for the next thread.

Answer (score 1):

My solution over here: https://gist.github.com/sinujohn/5fa717dfff680634c6b0c2a7eca108ac can be modified to achieve this. The idea is to create an object which holds the state and share that object among all the threads. There is only one synchronized block to access the shared state object.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        MyState state = new MyState();

        final Thread t1 = new Thread(new MyRunnable(10, 'A', state));
        final Thread t2 = new Thread(new MyRunnable(10, 'B', state));
        final Thread t3 = new Thread(new MyRunnable(10, 'C', state));
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
    }
}

class MyState {
    private char state = 'A';

    public char getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void incrState() {
        switch(state) {
        case 'A':
            state = 'B';
            return;
        case 'B':
            state = 'C';
            return;
        default:
            state = 'A';
        }
    }
}

class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    private final int max;
    private final char value;
    private final MyState state;

    MyRunnable(int max, char value, MyState state) {
        this.max = max;
        this.value = value;
        this.state = state;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int count = 0;
        while(count < max) {
            synchronized (this.state) {
                if (this.state.getState() == this.value) {
                    System.out.print(value);
                    count++;
                    this.state.incrState();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [CyclicBarrier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) ,this may help you              .

Answer (score 0):

You can use wait and notify for interthread communication. I am using turn int variable here for signaling among threads.

```
public class ThreadInterleaving{
    public static void main(String[] args){

    MyThread h = new MyThread();

    Thread t1 = new Thread(h);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(h);
    Thread t3 = new Thread(h);

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();

    }
}

class MyThread implements Runnable{
    public static int turn;

    @Override
    public void run(){
        for(int i =0;i<3;i++){
            synchronized(this){
                if(turn == 0){
                    System.out.println("Thread1");
                    turn =1 ;
                    notify();
                }else{
                    try{
                        wait();
                    }catch(InterruptedException ie){

                    }
                }

                if(turn == 1){
                    System.out.println("Thread2");
                    turn = 2;
                    notify();
                }else{
                    try{
                        wait();
                    }catch(InterruptedException ie){

                    }
                }

                if(turn == 2){
                    System.out.println("Thread3");
                    System.out.println("*********");
                    turn = 0;
                    notify();
                }else{
                    try{
                        wait();
                    }catch(InterruptedException ie){        

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

/*Output
Thread1
Thread2
Thread3
*********
Thread1
Thread2
Thread3
*********
Thread1
Thread2
Thread3
*********
Thread1
Thread2
Thread3
*********
Thread1
Thread2
Thread3
*********
Thread1
Thread2
Thread3
*********
Thread1
Thread2
Thread3
*********
Thread1
Thread2
Thread3
*********
Thread1
Thread2
Thread3
*********
*/
```

Comment: This looks like very odd code to me. Surely each thread should know which "turn" it owns, and wait for it to be that turn - currently *any* thread could print out "Thread1", *any* thread could print out "Thread2" and *any* thread could print out "Thread3", rather misleadingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RunningThreadSequentially {
    //Runnable task for each thread
    private static class Task implements Runnable {
        public static int counter=0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                synchronized(this) {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is completed--" + counter ++);             
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            } 
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        while(true) {
            Thread t1 = new Thread(new Task(), "Thread 1");
            Thread t2 = new Thread(new Task(), "Thread 2");
            Thread t3 = new Thread(new Task(), "Thread 3");
            Thread t4 = new Thread(new Task(), "Thread 4");
            Thread t5 = new Thread(new Task(), "Thread 5");
            Thread t6 = new Thread(new Task(), "Thread 6");

            t1.start();
            t1.join();
            t2.start();
            t2.join();
            t3.start(); 
            t3.join(); 
            t4.start(); 
            t4.join(); 
            t5.start();
            t5.join(); 
            t6.start(); 
            t6.join();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to this answer; it is of limited use without commentary.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class ThreadOrderTest {

int status = 1;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ThreadOrderTest threadOrderTest = new ThreadOrderTest();
    A a = new A(threadOrderTest);
    B b = new B(threadOrderTest);
    C c = new C(threadOrderTest);
    a.start();
    b.start();
    c.start();
}
}

class A extends Thread {

ThreadOrderTest threadOrderTest;

A(ThreadOrderTest threadOrderTest) {
    this.threadOrderTest = threadOrderTest;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        synchronized (threadOrderTest) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                while (threadOrderTest.status != 1) {
                    threadOrderTest.wait();
                }
                System.out.print("A ");
                threadOrderTest.status = 2;
                threadOrderTest.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception 1 :" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
}

class B extends Thread {

ThreadOrderTest threadOrderTest;

B(ThreadOrderTest threadOrderTest) {
    this.threadOrderTest = threadOrderTest;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        synchronized (threadOrderTest) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                while (threadOrderTest.status != 2) {
                    threadOrderTest.wait();
                }
                System.out.print("B ");
                threadOrderTest.status = 3;
                threadOrderTest.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception 2 :" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
}

class C extends Thread {

ThreadOrderTest threadOrderTest;

C(ThreadOrderTest threadOrderTest) {
    this.threadOrderTest = threadOrderTest;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        synchronized (threadOrderTest) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                while (threadOrderTest.status != 3) {
                    threadOrderTest.wait();
                }
                System.out.println("C ");
                threadOrderTest.status = 1;
                threadOrderTest.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception 3 :" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

[ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll%28java.util.Collection%29)

> An Executor that provides methods to manage termination and methods
>   that can produce a Future for tracking progress of one or more
>   asynchronous tasks.
>
> An ExecutorService can be shut down, which will cause it to reject new
>   tasks. Two different methods are provided for shutting down an
>   ExecutorService. The shutdown() method will allow previously submitted
>   tasks to execute before terminating, while the shutdownNow() method
>   prevents waiting tasks from starting and attempts to stop currently
>   executing tasks. Upon termination, an executor has no tasks actively
>   executing, no tasks awaiting execution, and no new tasks can be
>   submitted. An unused ExecutorService should be shut down to allow
>   reclamation of its resources.
>
> Method submit extends base method Executor.execute(java.lang.Runnable)
>   by creating and returning a Future that can be used to cancel
>   execution and/or wait for completion. Methods invokeAny and invokeAll
>   perform the most commonly useful forms of bulk execution, executing a
>   collection of tasks and then waiting for at least one, or all, to
>   complete. (Class ExecutorCompletionService can be used to write
>   customized variants of these methods.)
>
> The Executors class provides factory methods for the executor services
>   provided in this package.

Comment: How does this relate to the question at all?