# Primitives doesn't work to print an ordered sequence

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am supposing three threads: Pa, Pb and Pc such that Pa can only write the letter 'A', the Pb letter 'B' and Pc the letter 'C'. The three processes are in a loop from 1 to 100 and the only way out allowed is the alternation of the three letters: ABCABCABCABC ....

I have tried to follow this solution, **but primitives does not make any effect**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33655989/5183367.

There's an example:

```
class PHilo implements Runnable {
    public static int turn;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            synchronized (this) {
                if (turn == 0) {
                    System.out.print("A");
                    turn = 1;
                    notify();
                } else {
                    try {
                        wait();
                        System.out.println("Esperando para imprimir A");
                    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {

                    }
                }

                if (turn == 1) {
                    System.out.print("B");
                    turn = 2;
                    notify();

                } else {
                    try {
                        wait();
                        System.out.println("Esperando para imprimir B");
                    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {

                    }
                }

                if (turn == 2) {
                    System.out.print("C");
                    turn = 0;
                    notify();
                } else {
                    try {
                        wait();
                        System.out.println("Esperando para imprimir C");
                    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {

                    }
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Environment {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PHilo h = new PHilo();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(h);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(h);
        Thread t3 = new Thread(h);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();

    }
}
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve] rather than just referencing another question.

Comment: There's already an example!

Comment: Thank you - that example was *not* there when I added the comment. (It was added 3 minutes later.)

Comment: It's very confusing to me how this code is expected to work, to be honest - or which primitive you're talking about. This really isn't good code to start with, IMO - but I suggest you ask the original answerer for more details, rather than just posting a new question.

Comment: I may be wrong but you're synchronizing to each `Thread`, you should have a shared lock if you want the threads to be sync'd together.

Comment: Basically, you just copied the original answer and changed its name and the strings that are printed. The original answer was not very good. For one thing, `wait` should always be done in a loop to avoid spurious wakeups. Another thing is that it's not recommended to synchronize on the runnable of the current thread. It's better to dedicate a specific object for the lock. Lastly, it's still not clear what the problem is. Explain what happens when you use this code and why this is not correct, and what the connection is to primitives.

Comment: Also, with this code each `Thread` will print `ABC` because there's no way to tell which one has to print `A` or `B` or `C`.

Comment: I thought there's another better way to use sync primitives. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you started from a question with no accepted reply, I'm adding mine here so that you can see if this is what you needed.

This one's built based on the code you had, so probably there could be a better way to do it.

I've added comments on the code so that you can see what I did and why.

```
class PHilo implements Runnable {

    public static int turn;

    // First of all we need a shared lock so that every thread can use it
    // Using synchronized(this) won't synchronize at all because each thread will synchronize on itself
    private final static Object lock = new Object();

    // Then we need a way to let each thread know what it should print
    // Following your convention, if myTurn is 0 it'll print A and so on
    private final int myTurn;

    // That's why I added this constructor
    public PHilo(int myTurn) {
        this.myTurn = myTurn;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            // Now we're syncing on lock which is shared, this prevents 2 thread from printing together and only one is allowed each time
            synchronized (lock) {
                // We need to wait while it's not our turn, and we use the while to prevent spurious wakeups
                while (myTurn != turn) {
                    try {
                        // We wait on the shared lock
                        lock.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                    }
                }
                // If we're here it means that we can print since it's our turn, so let's decide what to print
                switch (myTurn) {
                    case 0: {
                        System.out.print("A");
                        turn = 1;
                        // There's no need to notify here
                        break;
                    }
                    case 1: {
                        System.out.print("B");
                        turn = 2;
                        break;
                    }
                    case 2: {
                        System.out.print("C");
                        turn = 0;                            
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // It's always a good idea to use notifyAll instead of notify, so that we can awake all the waiting threads
                // It's thread's responsibility to check if it may run after the notifyAll, so we just wake all of them and let them choose who can go on
                lock.notifyAll();
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}

class Environment {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // We use the parameter for PHilo to identify the different threads
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new PHilo(0));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new PHilo(1));
        Thread t3 = new Thread(new PHilo(2));

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();

    }
}
```

This is the output that I get, hoping that is what you asked for:

```
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. That's just what I need. A right development by primitives, that depends on them to work fine.

Comment: Synchronization primitives, @steptnt.